# what to edit in the android app working folder

Tags: android, eclipse, directory

I have the code for an wallpaper app and want to use the same code to create a new app with different app name and by changing the pics, so which files are need to be edited in the working folder by using eclipse to make a new app.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new project with a new package name. Then you can just copy and paste your old code into your new project, and change whatever you need to change. If you morph your current project into a whole different app you cannot publish it with the same package name. Furthermore you will not be able to support future updates of your current app since you are essentially scrubbing it.

Comment: as i should change the package name, while changing the packaging name it is showing all errors in .java and manifest.xml files.  so what are the files to change with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Create project from existing source and Rename the package via right clicking your package under src folder and selecting  **Refactor->Rename...** as shown in the picture:
[image]
Now enter new package name and select those options as shown in the below picture:
[image]

Then click **Preview>** and on the next window click **ok**. That's it, your package will be successfully renamed. Follow this process to rename anything you want. You can change appearance name of app by changing **android:label** in manifest file :)